# React Router (entering infinite Loop) :Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my React router Code snippet.

I am using React Router to Route. I am using nginx as my server.

```
var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory')
var history = createBrowserHistory()

var Router = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={Navbar}>
               <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    }
});

module.exports = Router
```

I am getting the error Maximum call stack size exceeded (which i think means it is looping)

here is my nginx file :

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;
location ^~ /static/ {
    root /home/sijan/personal/webpack;
}

location / {

    root /home/sijan/personal/webpack/static;
    rewrite .* /static/index.html last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

I have used the same technique in other project with many routes and I have not got any issues. But here , i am trying to make a simple website and i am receiving this error and i am not sure how to fix this.(/dont know if the nginx or the react code i wrote )

Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: I wonder if there isn'a problem that your component is called Router as the react-router component. Can you try renaming it to something else?

I would try to isolate the react code from the nginx setup to figure out if the problem is caused by the nginx config or your react code. Did you try running your react app using webpack-dev-server? Or if your app is not large, you could try to create a codepen with your react code, like [this one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNGZJP?editors=1111).

Comment: Yes i am using webpack. webpack -w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the cause to the issue.

The following is my actual required libraries.

```
var Router=require('react-router').Router
var Route=require('react-router').Route
var IndexRoute=require('react-router').IndexRoute
var Index = require('./index')
var Navbar = require('./navbar')
var Content = require('./content')


var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory')
var history = createBrowserHistory()

var Router = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
                <Route path="content" component={Content}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    }
});
module.exports = Router;
```

And as you can clearly see, i have included two variables with same name( i.e ROUTER)

This was the cause for the referred Issue.

I just changed the name of one of the Router to Router1 and the code works perfectly.

Hope this helps for someone else.